# Wildlfy with Nginx not working properly

Tags: nginx, wildfly

We had installed wildfly for a couple of time working correctly. We configured right now Nginx as reverse proxy for wildfly.

We're getting on `OPTIONS` method `405 Method Not Allowed`. Here is the configuration of nginx.

- /etc/nginx/conf.d/wildfly.conf

  ```
  upstream wildfly {
       server 127.0.0.1:8081;
  }

  server {
      listen 8080;
      server_name guest1;

      location/ {  
          proxy_pass http://wildfly;
       }
  }
  ```

  - Error obtained after installing nginx:

[image]

This is the error got by nginx:

> 2017/06/23 08:16:54 [crit] 1386#0: *9 connect() to 127.0.0.1:8081 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.28.128.1, server: guest1, request: "OPTIONS /commty/cmng/users HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/commty/cmng/users", host: "guest1:8080"

What I'm missing?

Comment: What does the nginx log say? Does it forward the options request to wildfly? Based on your pic it us not possible to say. Also how does wildfly handle the request to url `commty/cmgt/users`? Do you have a rest endpoint there or servlet?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't answer since now. I have rest endpoint. I updated the answer with the nginx error log.

Comment: ok, now what about your wildfly log? Did the nginx manage to get through to it? If yes, what does your wifldly say. If no, try to check if SElinux is enabled, try running `sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx | grep denied`.

Comment: nothing appears on wildfly. Same for audit. The only place that I can see something is on /var/log/nginx/error.log. If I try a normal acces (for example, accessing with guest1:8080) I can see the wildfly default webpage and all works ok. If I try guest1:8080/commty/cmng/users it doesn't work

Comment: In audit I found this message: type=AVC msg=audit(1498207468.887:68): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=876 comm="nginx" dest=8081 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:transproxy_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket

Comment: ok, so what happens if you try to access your rest endpoint directly on wildfly via `GET http://127.0.0.1:8081/commty/cmgt/users` ? Do you have security enabled for your web app? What HTTP method does your endpoint allow? You can turn on undertow request logging to see if the request got through: [see this blog for example](https://mirocupak.com/logging-requests-with-undertow/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147438/discussion-between-yntelectual-and-lechucico).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done the following to finally make it work on `CentOS7 + Wildfly`.

- Vagrant up
- Install NGINX

  - yum install epel-release
  - yum install nginx
- Configure /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (default configuration)
- Configure /etc/nginx/conf.d/wildfly.conf (using port 80 for nginx and 8080 for wildfly)

  ```
  upstream wildfly {
      server 127.0.0.1:8080;
  }

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name guest1;

      location / {  
          proxy_pass http://wildfly;
       }
  }
  ```

Also set SELinux permissive for let nginx work.

`$ setenforce permissive`

After that wildfly is working properly through nginx.